# Modelmapper issue while handling @OnetoOne mapping

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, modelmapper

I have a an issue in using modelmapper to perform an update of a parent-child entity using `@OneToOne`.

The description is as follows

**Parent Class**:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table (name = "site")
public class Site {

  @Id
  @JsonIgnore
  @Column(name = "internal_id")
  private long internalId;

  @Column(name = "internal_uuid")
  private String internalUUID;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "site", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Address address;

  // Some other stuff
}
```

**Child class**:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "address")
public class Address {

  @Id
  @JsonIgnore
  @Column(name = "internal_id")
  private Long internalId;

  @JsonIgnore
  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "site_uuid", referencedColumnName = "internal_uuid")
  private Site site;

  // Some other stuff  
}
```

With this arrangement I am able to create and query a site + address combination successfully. However I face a problem while doing an update. I am trying to update a site, or an address using a modelmapper statement as follows:

```
modelmapper.map(site_from_request, site_existing_in_db);
```

The expectation is that all fields that are changed in the incoming site (i.e. site_from_request) should replace the existing fields in site_existing_in_db. However I get a Stackoverflow error from modelmapper.

Is there a way we can instruct the modelmapper to skip the field mapping of Site (under Address)? All the examples I have come across, point to skipping of fields under the parent class itself (i.e Site) and not Address.
I have tried alternatives like BeanUtils.copyProperties (provided by Spring) but there too I do not see an option to skip fields that belong to a child.

Thanks a lot,
Prabal

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to create a `TypeMap` for `Address` to `Address` conversion and set `Site` skipped in that, so like:

```
modelMapper
    .createTypeMap(Address.class, Address.class)
    .addMappings(new PropertyMap<Address, Address>() {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            skip(destination.getSite());
        }
    });
```